Is it possible to get Chat GPT answer as using model 'whisper' as Stream in Flutter app?
I want to ask question in voice and get answer in voice as speaking with chat gpt in Flutter app.
For this, I used package dart_openai and flutter_tts.
But I found that chat gpt's voice is more like person and they already opened model whisper.
And even package dart_openai that I used also has this model whisper.
link: dart_openai
But when I search the part that uses model whisper from documentation, it is below:

Audio
Create Speech
For creating a speech from a text, you can use the createSpeech()
method directly by providing the required params:

// The speech request. File speechFile = await
OpenAI.instance.audio.createSpeech(   model: "tts-1",   input: "Say my
name is Anas",   voice: "nova",   responseFormat:
OpenAIAudioSpeechResponseFormat.mp3,   outputDirectory: await
Directory("speechOutput").create(),   outputFileName: "anas", );

// The file result. print(speechFile.path);

Note: the outputDirectory and outputFileName are helpers for this
method, you can use them to save the audio file to a specific
directory with a specific name, with the file extension being
extracted from the responseFormat. if you don't want to use them, just
ignore it, and the audio file will be saved to the default directory
of your app, with the output file name.
The example snippet above will place a generated anas.mp3 in the
speechOutput directory in your project.
Create transcription
For transcribing an audio File, you can use the createTranscription()
method directly by providing the file property:
OpenAIAudioModel transcription =
OpenAI.instance.audio.createTranscription(   file: File(/* THE FILE
PATH*/),   model: "whisper-1",   responseFormat:
OpenAIAudioResponseFormat.json, );

// print the transcription. print(transcription.text);



It seems just read text after completing getting answer..
So my understanding is that after I get answer from AI and convert it to voice as using model whisper API.
Which means we need two steps.
Is my understanding correct?
I can't find any example code that embodies the voice conversation process with chat gpt as asking question in user voice and getting answer in AI voice without package flutter_tts especially as stream in Flutter project.
And the current chat gpt's human voice is really like human but whisper is not like that much, I think.
Is it right that API's capability is less than real chat gpt?
